# How to use relative paths in a notebook?

Tags: files-and-directories

To maintain mobility of project files, I want to use relative paths in my notebooks. For example, I have a directory named "proj" and my notebook file is located in this directory. Meanwhile, I have to import something from directory "proj/data/". How do I get a relative path to "data"? I want to do this because I might move "proj" somewhere else in my file system.

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate.  If you feel that your question is not addressed there please tell me why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is data directory (OS independent) :-

```
FileNameJoin@Append[FileNameSplit@NotebookDirectory[], "data"]
```

Comment: Why not just `FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "data"}]`?

Comment: Yup, somehow missed that.  Thanks.